# Interior points of closed vs open intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking at a review question, which asks if $1, 1.9, 2, 2.1$ are interior points of $(0,2)$. From my understanding, 1 and 1.9 are in fact interior points, 2, 2.1 are not. The follow up question is, what about $[0,2]$? My intuition tells me that it should be the same as before, but I can't be sure. Can someone explain to me why I'm wrong/ if I'm wrong? How can I prove that 2, 2.1 are **not** in the interior of (0,2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interior of any set is a subset of the set itself, so since neither $2$ nor $2.1$ are even elements of $(0,2)$ they are in particular not in its interior.

The same argument shows that $2.1$ is not an interior point of $[0,2]$.

To show that $2$ is not an interior point of $[0,2]$ you would probably go directly to the definition. Thus you need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ the ball $(2-\varepsilon,2+\varepsilon)$ contains a point that is *not* in $[0,2]$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! So then I can just say that in the real line (which is what I'm currently working in), even taking an infinitely small $\epsilon$ leaves me with a point outside of my set $[0,2]$ right?

Comment: @DarpanGanatra: In ordinary real analysis there is no "infinitely small" $\varepsilon$. There are only _finite (put possibly small)_ $\varepsilon$s. So what you should be saying is "no matter how small $\varepsilon$ is ...".

Comment: I see, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $[0,2]$, $2$ is a boundary point and $2.1$ is an exterior point.

By definition of interior point we should be able to find a radius such that ball around $2$ of that radius is fully contained in $(0,2)$ or $[0,2]$. But any ball around $2$ contains points outside $(0,2)$ or $[0,2]$.